# Breaking on exception: Strict get failed, invalid object. (dart)

Tags: dart, strict

I wasn't able to find anything helpful through google, so:
My Dart webapplication worked perfectly. Next time I opened Darteditor and (without changing anything) ran it again, Darteditor showed the Error

> Breaking on exception: Strict get failed, invalid object.

This Error doesn't always show up and even when it does, the App still functions. Darteditor doesn't give me any hit where that Error occurs, because the debugger claims some source not to be available.

[image: Screenshot]

Does anyone know why/when this Error occurrs and what to do to fix it?

---

EDIT 1:
As suggested in comments:

- updating Darteditor
- `pub cache repair`
- `pub upgrade`

Did not work

---

EDIT 2:
A Day after I tried the things mentioned in EDIT 1. Thus also after I rebooted the PC. At the moment, the Error doesn't appear anymore. I tried restarting the Darteditor after each try in EDIT 1 but nothing changed. Now...some of the things in EDIT 1 seem to have taken effect only after rebooting the PC. Not sure which of those though - am I supposed to answer my own question mentioning all 3 options from EDIT 1 or what should I do?

---

EDIT 3:
(Sorry for all the edits)
I changed some code now and the Error is back here again...
Sometimes it goes away, but not with a obvious reason like a specific line of code added/removed. Right now, ther is an additional line by the Error:

> Application Cache NoUpdate event (https://www.google.ch/xjs/_/js/k=xjs.ntp.en_US.mqcA3JMW-QU.O/m=jsa,ntp,pcc,csi/rt=j/d=1/t=zcms/rs=AItRSTO3mHFV3hPPmf2KYlzqp_GC2s-5GQ:119)
>   Breaking on exception: Strict get failed, invalid object.

Comment: What Dart version are you using?

Comment: Dart Editor version 1.4.2.release (STABLE)
Dart SDK version 1.4.2

I have an update available, but when the error ocurred first, I checked for updates and had none. should I update it now?

Comment: Current stable is 1.5.8. Updating would be useful.

Comment: updated, but didn't help. Error also occurrs with an other Dart app

Comment: Run `pub cache repair` (on the command line) and try again.

Comment: Try also `pub upgrade`. Otherwise I have no idea. I have never seen this error before.

Comment: Doing so in darteditor: No dependancies changed
Doing so with cmd in the folder where pub.bat is: 
F:\Programme\Programme\dart\dart-sdk\bin>pub upgrade
Error in pubspec.yaml:
Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "F:\Programme\Programme\dart\dart-
sdk\bin".

Comment: On the command line you need to run `pub upgrade` in the directory where the `pubspec.yaml` file of your application is.

Comment: how would I do this? The command `pub` is only known in the folder where the pub.bat is. would it be safe to simply copy the pub.bat in my other folder where the pubspec.yaml is?

Comment: Copy the file wouldn't help. You should add `F:\Programme\Programme\dart\dart-sdk\bin` to your path. http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. Doing so results in the same as in the darteditor: No dependencies changed

Comment: You can answer your own question. Don't forget to accept it (only possible after some delay) but then everyone sees that you are not waiting for an answer anymore.

Comment: The behavior is very weird. Can you try on another PC or some fresh VM ?

Comment: yes I can, thy for the idea, I'll comment or edit when I tried it. I have right now not access to the other PC

Comment: This is the 2nd time I saw this exception http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189205

Comment: On an other computer using a clean install, the error doesn't occurr. I will try a clean install on my main PC tomorrow.

Comment: Do you use Angular or DI? https://github.com/angular/di.dart/issues/161

Comment: I didn't hear of angular before. if you mean [link](https://angulardart.org/) then no, I don't use angular. if you mean what imports I use, those would be the following: `dart:html`, `dart:convert`and `dart:js`

Comment: Not sure how to uninstall Darteditor. Tried to delete `C:\Users\myName\DartEditor` which made the welcome screen pop up again in darteditor and the folder was recreated (containing less subfolders than before), but the Error still showed up after the 3th time running my app

Comment: I get the same error message when I click the back button in Dartium, or when I use the backspace key and the focus is not in an editable field (which triggers the back button). I think it's either a bug in Dart or Dartium.

Comment: Interesting: When I pressed the back button in dartium, the error did show up, but after this, it said something about application cache (about 5 lines of text) and now I cannot reproduce the "strict get failed" Error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get the same error message when I click the back button in Dartium,
>   or when I use the backspace key and the focus is not in an editable
>   field (which triggers the back button). I think it's either a bug in
>   Dart or Dartium. –  Damien Aug 21 at 14:00
>
> Interesting: When I pressed the back button in dartium, the error did
>   show up, but after this, it said something about application cache
>   (about 5 lines of text) and now I cannot reproduce the "strict get
>   failed" Error message –  lucidbrot yesterday

**pressing the back button in dartium**, which I never did before, seemed to help in my case. Updating Darteditor again after this didn't change anything - the strict get error disappeared.

I won't accept this answer until somebody comments that it worked for him too, but I guess it is better to view here than as a comment to my question.