# How do you fix upgrade

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm 3 months new into dart and I've been fairly lucky not to have encountered any issues that couldn't be fixed from answers found on the net, but this one has stumped me.

I downloaded this sample app (https://github.com/vsavkin/angulardart-sample-app) installed it into dart-editor (on my mac mini) using Open Existing Folder and then running get Pub Get (or even Pub Update) on the pubspec.yaml file.

I was getting dartium loading with a running app until I upgraded the SDK from 1.4.2 to 1.5.8 and the pubspec.yaml file from

environment:
sdk: '>=1.4.2 <2.0.0' to

environment:
sdk: '>=1.5.8 <2.0.0'

where everything just broke and i am now getting these types of errors in dartium which I'd like to know how to fix (reverting hasn't helped, 404's are still present - is there some old cache that's being read that I can't find?):

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) `http://localhost:63342/aa-app/packages/shadow_dom/shadow_dom.min.js`

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) `http://localhost:63342/aa-app/web/packages/angular/routing/static_keys.dart`
An error occurred loading file: package:angular/routing/static_keys.dart package:angular/routing/static_keys.dart:1

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) `http://localhost:63342/aa-app/web/packages/angular/cache/module.dart`
An error occurred loading file: package:angular/cache/module.dart package:angular/cache/module.dart:1

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) `http://localhost:63342/aa-app/web/packages/angular/core_dom/directive_injector.dart`
An error occurred loading file: package:angular/core_dom/directive_injector.dart package:angular/core_dom/directive_injector.dart:1

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) `http://localhost:63342/aa-app/web/packages/angular/cache/js_cache_register.dart`
An error occurred loading file: package:angular/cache/js_cache_register.dart package:angular/cache/js_cache_register.dart:1

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) `http://localhost:63342/aa-app/web/packages/angular/directive/static_keys.dart`
An error occurred loading file: package:angular/directive/static_keys.dart package:angular/directive/static_keys.dart:1

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) `http://localhost:63342/aa-app/web/packages/angular/core/static_keys.dart`
An error occurred loading file: package:angular/core/static_keys.dart package:angular/core/static_keys.dart:1

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) `http://localhost:63342/aa-app/web/packages/di/src/reflector.dart`
An error occurred loading file: package:di/src/reflector.dart package:di/src/reflector.dart:1

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) `http://localhost:63342/aa-app/web/packages/angular/change_detection/ast_parser.dart`
An error occurred loading file: package:angular/change_detection/ast_parser.dart package:angular/change_detection/ast_parser.dart:1

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) `http://localhost:63342/aa-app/web/packages/angular/core_dom/compiler_config.dart`
An error occurred loading file: package:angular/core_dom/compiler_config.dart package:angular/core_dom/compiler_config.dart:1

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) `http://localhost:63342/aa-app/web/packages/di/check_bind_args.dart`
An error occurred loading file: package:di/check_bind_args.dart package:di/check_bind_args.dart:1

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) `http://localhost:63342/aa-app/web/packages/di/src/reflector_dynamic.dart`
An error occurred loading file: package:di/src/reflector_dynamic.dart package:di/src/reflector_dynamic.dart:1

Have tried starting from scratch
Have tried different versions of the angular package ie version 11.0, 12.0, 13.0
Have tried different versions of SDK from 1.4.2 to 1.5.3 to 1.5.8 still the same output

What on earth have i done to ruin something that was working so slickly?

Comment: I had just a brief glance. The `shadow_dom` package is deprecated since several months. Use `web_components` instead. Are you using IntelliJ IDEA/WebStorm? Try running `pub serve` and load the file from `http://localhost:8080/index.html` (for `web/index.html` file).

Comment: i removed shadow_dom but it is still showing up in the 404 errors

Comment: I didn't expect this to solve your problem but I hadn't more time.
You haven't yet answered if you are using DartEditor or a WebStorm. The port 63342 and the path shown by your error messages is uncommon for DartEditor.

Comment: Sorry  not used to this. first time in Stackoverflow... Yes I am using intelliJ Webstorm, but I am also using the dart editor too especially for debugging. 
I removed shadow_dom and run upgrade (using dart-editor), but it is still showing up in the 404 errors along with all those others.
And when dartium now loads I get this message (having gone back to 1.4.2 from 1.5.8)
Your profile can not be used because it is from a newer version of Chromium.
Some features may be unavailable. Please specify a different profile directory or use a newer version of Chromium. I broken everything it seems.

Comment: I'm now only using dart-editor and have things partially working but still getting 404, however, when I click the link in dartium's console eg. the error:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://127.0.0.1:8080/lib/components/call.html
clicking it shows in browser... Could not find asset web/lib/components/agenda.html in package talk_to_me. The path web/lib does not exist how can I correct this?

Comment: This is still with Savkins example linked above?

Comment: Yes. Started from scratch at 14:18 today, it runs out of box on dart-editor 1.5.8 with a Pub Upgrade to get rid of red markers.
Upgrading pubspec.yaml from angular: ">=0.11.0 <0.12.0" to angular: ">=0.12.0 <0.13.0" works fine, but then to ">=0.13.0 <0.14.0" causes: Breaking on exception: Module.DEFAULT_REFLECTOR not initialized for dependency injection.http://goo.gl/XFXx9G
Upgrading sdk: ">=0.8.10 <2.0.0" to  sdk: ">=1.5.8 <2.0.0" with angular back to "0.12.0"  causes Uncaught Strict get failed, invalid object. (twice) with
the same Breaking on exception as above
but 404's now gone.

Comment: This weird exception with `Strict get failed` also came up at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25182118 (without a solution)

Comment: I also had this error about `Module.DEFAULT_REFLECTOR` (non-Angular app using DI). I don't know what causes it. I found a workaround for now by passing an reflector with the super call like `class RoutingModule extends Module { RoutingModule() : super.withReflector(new DynamicTypeFactories()) { ... } }`.

Comment: In this case would that be:
class TalkToMeApp extends Module { TalkToMeApp() : super.withReflector(new DynamicTypeFactories()) { bind(SomeCtrl); bind(AnotherCtrl);}}
If so that causes: Exception: Module.DEFAULT_REFLECTOR not initialized for dependency injection.http://goo.gl/XFXx9G (package:di/src/reflector_null.dart:11)
Breaking on exception: Module.DEFAULT_REFLECTOR not initialized for dependency injection.http://goo.gl/XFXx9G
I suspect this is down to my greenhorn error. And thanks for the pointer earlier. I too will try to do this on another machine... Linux Ubuntu in my case

Comment: I guess you should file a bug report in the DI repo.

Comment: I've never filed a bug before so how do I do that please. This is my first time doing any of this stuff. By the way, before I do that, do I have to import anything for the new DynamicTypeFactories() because that has a yellow line underneath it?

Comment: Report your problem at https://github.com/angular/di.dart/issues and add a link to this SO question and also link your SO question to the created issue.

Comment: You my not have caught my edit... By the way, before I do that, do I have to import anything for the new DynamicTypeFactories() because that has a yellow line underneath it? Says it is undefined. What do i use (package etc.) to define it?

Comment: import 'package:di/src/reflector_dynamic.dart';

Comment: No good, still the same error eventhough new DynamicTypeFactories() is being found by the import 'package:di/src/reflector_dynamic.dart';: 
Exception: Module.DEFAULT_REFLECTOR not initialized for dependency injection.http://goo.gl/XFXx9G (package:di/src/reflector_null.dart:11)
Breaking on exception: Module.DEFAULT_REFLECTOR not initialized for dependency injection.http://goo.gl/XFXx9G
Going to file that bug report.
Thanks for all your help though and lightening fast responses... appreciated

Comment: I have now filed a bug report at this address: https://github.com/angular/di.dart/issues/161

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error "Module.DEFAULT_REFLECTOR not initialized" is thrown because the di transformer is not executed.

You need to add the anfular transformer to your pubspec.yaml (which includes the di transformer)

Comment: Hi Victor, I have this in an (simple demo) app that uses only `di` (with Polymer). Is there a di-only transformer that solves this?

Comment: Seems I got it. I had the `di` transformer in `pubspec.yaml`. For Polymer I don't need a `main()` (it provides its own main()) but the `di` transformer seems to require one. I created a custom `main()` method and imported one file from the `lib` directory. That did it.

Comment: Although this fixes the issue for an upgrade to angular 0.12.0 another issue is caused by a further upgrade to angular 0.13.0 see: https://github.com/vsavkin/angulardart-sample-app/pull/20 the error caused is: Breaking on exception: Type 'DynamicMetadataExtractor' not found in generated typeFactory maps